# find the last occurrence of a value in an array vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I would like to find the reference of the last occurrence of a value within an array.

The array has values in a format similar to `(0,7,7,7,7,7,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,16)`, with a boolean in the second column.

I believe that FINDLAST is the function that I am looking for but I am unable to get the syntax to work.

EDIT:

I have the position of one of the occurrences within the array `CursorPosition` and from that I want to find the final occurrence within the array. My code is currently:

```
CursorPosition = position.FindLast(position, position(0, CursorPosition))
```

I am currently getting 3 errors:

> Type parameter 'T' for 'Public Shared Function FindLast(Of T)(array() As T, match As System.Predicate(Of T)) As T' cannot be inferred.
>
> Type argument inference failed for type parameter 'T' of 'Public Shared Function FindLast(Of T)(array() As T, match As System.Predicate(Of T)) As T'. Type argument could not be inferred from the argument passed to parameter 'array'.
>
> Type argument inference failed for type parameter 'T' of 'Public Shared Function FindLast(Of T)(array() As T, match As System.Predicate(Of T)) As T'. Type argument could not be inferred from the argument passed to parameter 'match'.

Comment: "I am unable to get the syntax to work" is not a good description of your problem. Please explain _what_ you tried (code example, if possible), what the results were (including errors and exceptions if any).

Comment: @Oded I have updated the questions with more details as requested.

Comment: What _value_ are you looking for? What should `CursorPosition` be after that line runs?

Comment: The reference of the last occurrence of the value it refers to.
So for the example array above, it could start as 3. Which refers to a 7. I want the final value to come out as 5, which is the reference of the last 7.

Comment: `FindLast` returns the _item_ not its position.

Comment: ok, So how about `FindIndex`? I just tried that within my code and I still have similar errors.

Comment: `FindIndex` always returns the _first occurrence_. You really should read the MSDN documentation on these functions.

Comment: Not sure why you can't simply loop through the array - a simple function to write.

Comment: I accidentally read the wrong MSDN for `FindIndex` I apologise
`findlastindex` I could write a loop but I don't have the experience to think of doing that, which is why i came here asking for help because generally people here do help. You could have said that in the first place, or you could have said `findlastindex` in the first place but you didn't...

Comment: I _am_ trying to help - I believe that teaching a man to fish it better than giving him a fish. But with this kind of attitude, forget it...

Comment: @Oded There is a difference between teaching to fish and watching someone cast and telling them they are doing it wrong. Anyway I shall go and look at looping function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the Array.FindLast() and Array.FindLastIndex() methods.  The last argument is a *predicate*, a delegate type.  In other words, the method needs a function that it can pass candidate values to and it should return True when there's a match.

Such a predicate is most easily implemented with a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).  Check out the link for the details.  A simple example:

```
    Dim position() As Integer = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}
    Dim tofind = 2
    Dim index = Array.FindLastIndex(position, Function(value) value = tofind)
```